# Why doesn’t the watchOS beta profile show up in my list of available downloads?

Tags: data-transfer, watchos, beta

I am trying to install the watchOS 6 beta profile to my watch from an iPhone X running iOS 13 beta.

At https://developer.apple.com/watchos/ I see a link to a downloads page that should link the profile, but after I am sent to https://developer.apple.com/download/ I only see a download for the Xcode 11 beta.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you signed in with your Apple Developer account?

Comment: I am signed in with my developer account, but it’s not currently a paid account. FWIW, I was able to download and install the profiles for iOS 13 beta and macOS 10.15 beta.

Comment: When I go to https://developer.apple.com/download/ I can see the watchOS beta profile.  I do have a paid account but I don't think that should impact what's seen.  Maybe it's not offered for you location?

Comment: @fsb naa, I’m in San Francisco, CA.

Comment: Ok, then I don't know of any other answer.  The section is there, I just used it to update my Watch (assuming you have a Watch registered with the same account).  Have you tried using a different device or browser?  Maybe have someone else try with their account on your machine?  I'm grasping for straws on this.